# How to use StreamBuilder with Firestore at flutter web?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I'm building a site with flutter web, but I cant fetch the data from firestore to a StreamBuilder because the onSnapshot is not working...

I'm using this package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firestore.dart' as fs;

class Playground extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PlaygroundState createState() => _PlaygroundState();
}

class _PlaygroundState extends State<Playground> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    fs.Firestore dataBase = firestore();
    fs.CollectionReference teachersRef = dataBase.collection('teachers');

return Center(
  child: Container(
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
    color: Colors.cyanAccent,
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: teste.collection('teachers').onSnapshot,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading...');
        return ListView.builder(
          //itemExtent: 30,
          itemCount: 4,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: 10,
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Text(snapshot.data[index]['name']),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

But I get this answer:

['[]'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: Instance of 'QuerySnapshot'
Arguments: [0]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AQ2N.png)

Do anyone know how to use Firestore properly at Flutter web?

Comment: hope you included the `<script>` tags in the `index.html`. Also where is the `teste`variable defined. I don't see it. Also try giving an initial value to the stream builder.

Comment: Hi, did you ever get this to work? every time I use onSnapshot and snapshot.hasData I get nothing back from my collection or document requests..

Comment: Hii! Yes, I figured out how to use...

Comment: To get the data you need to type snapshot.data.data()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is related to final build line

```
child: Text(snapshot.data[index]['name']),
```

The snapshot data is a `QuerySnapshot` from the `JScript` import and not the `AsyncQuerySnapshot` you were exepcting.

I amended to call with some success

```
child: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].get('name')),
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue but your answer doesn't work for me. I'm not getting the option to choose ```.docs``` after snapshot.data, or ```.get('')```. Any time I have tried to use a StreamBuilder I get a blank screen..

Answer (score 1):

i think your problem is here :

```
fs.CollectionReference teachersRef = dataBase.collection('teachers');
```

Try with this instead:

```
final teachersRef = Firestore.instance.collection('teachers');
```

Now you can use **teachersRef** to get a snapshot and use it in your **StreamBuilder**

Comment: This does not work, this library does not have the ".instance" parameter, so I cant use this syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should be using the `firestore()` initializer function. And you should have the  `<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>` line in your code and have it initialized in your main. 
the example code are the following:

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Your web app title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```dart
// your main function
void main(){
   initializeApp(
      apiKey: "{YOUR  API KEY}",
      authDomain: "{YOUR AUTH DOMAIN}",
      databaseURL: "{YOUR DATABASE URL}",
      projectId: "{YOUR PROJECT ID}",
      storageBucket: "{YOUR STORAGE BUCKET}",
      messagingSenderId: "{YOUR MESSAGING SENDER ID}",
    );
    runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Your actual class that uses the library

```dart
import 'package:firebase/firestore.dart';

class FirebaseHandler {
  FirebaseHandler({Firestore firestoreInstance,})
      : _firestore = firestoreInstance ?? firestore(); // firestore() is the default initializer for your firebase APP firestore.
   final Firestore _firestore;

   Stream getCollection(String collection){
      try {
         return  _firestore.collection(collection + "/").onSnapshot;
      } catch (e) {
         print('Error retrieving snapshot: $e');
         throw '$e';
      }
   }
}
```